# Invalidation of token JWT

Tags: architecture, jwt

let's say we have situation like this:

Backend generated JWT token which is valid for 4 hours. One hour after this backend get shutdown for some unknown reason (general it is not working). Should this token be valid or backend should invalidate him somehow? What is proper approach to this.

Comment: A token - once issued - cannot be invalidated on itself. If resource servers do token validation "on their own" (i.e. without contacting the token issuer), the token cannot be invalidated at all. Only way to invalidate the token is to mark it as invalidated in the token issuer. This - as stated above - requires that all resource servers contact the token issuer for validation.

Comment: Why should the token be invalid just because your backend is down? Assuming the backend in question is your login system this would mean that after your login backend is down nobody, not even the already logged in users, would be able to interact with your other backend anymore... Who would even invalidate the token??

Answer (score 0):

In case of OAuth there are least 2 backend systems in this authorization process: Authorization and Resource Servers.

- Authorization Server issues the JWT token to grant access for the client for a given resource
- Resource Server checks the validity of the JWT token and may grant or deny the access request

[image: oauth jwt]
([Source](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication/jwt-flow))

Depending on the fact the Authorization Server issues a refresh token or not, a new access token can be requested automatically or manually.

---

Back to your example:

- Auth Server issues a JWT token with 4 hours validity
- Auth Server is down after one hour

> Should this token be valid or backend should invalidate him somehow?

The Auth Server has granted access for 4 hours to the requester for a given resource. If the Resource Server is able to determine the validity of the JWT token without the involvement of Auth Server then the availability of the Auth Server should not have any impact on the resource access.